# Calculate the balance

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with the transactions . and an opening balance . I need to calculate opening and closing balance ,query is not working as expect. Can you please guide me.

**Input :**

[image]

Input 2

[image]

I need to calculate opening and closing balance.
Open Balance= Prev_close_balance

[image]

**Query**

```
 SELECT TRANS_ID,TRANS_AMOUNT ,open_bal,
       lag(open_bal) over ( order by TRANS_AMOUNT)-TRANS_AMOUNT prev_close
FROM trans_t a INNER JOIN open_bal  b
ON a.CUST_ID=b.CUST_ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want window functions, but a cumulative `sum()` not `lag()`:

```
SELECT t.*,
       b.open_bal + t.trans_amount - sum(t.trans_amount) over (order by t.trans_id) as open_balance,
       b.open_bal - sum(t.trans_amount) over (order by t.trans_id) as close_balance
FROM trans_t t INNER JOIN
     open_bal  b
     ON t.CUST_ID = b.CUST_ID;
```

The logic is simple.  For any given transaction, the closing balance is the initial opening balance minus the sum of the transactions.  The opening balance just adds that transaction's amount back in.